# How to perform aggregation in mongodb using Java by setting query object instead of matchoperation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Below is the code:

```
            Criteria criteria=null;
            criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("OwnerId").is(ownerId), Criteria.where("Environment").is(env), Criteria.where("ServiceName").in(api));
            MatchOperation matchOp= Aggregation.match(criteria);
            ProjectionOperation projOp= Aggregation.project("SubServices").andInclude("ServerGroupName").andInclude("NodeName").andInclude("ServiceVersion")
                    .andExclude("_id");
            Aggregation aggr = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOp, projOp);
            AggregationResults<Document> aggregate = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggr, "CNF_SERVICE",Document.class,"config",env);
```

The above code works fine. However, I need to make below changes in order to generate criteria dynamically:

```
            Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
            Query query= new Query();
            if(ownerId!=null && ownerId>0) {
                query.addCriteria(criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("OwnerId").is(ownerId)));
            }
            if(env!=null) {
                query.addCriteria(criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("Environment").is(env)));
            }
            if(api!=null) {
                query.addCriteria(criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("ServiceName").in(api)));
            }
            MatchOperation matchOp= Aggregation.match("How to set the query here?");
            ProjectionOperation projOp= Aggregation.project("SubServices").andInclude("ServerGroupName").andInclude("NodeName").andInclude("ServiceVersion")
                    .andExclude("_id");
            Aggregation aggr = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOp, projOp);
            AggregationResults<Document> aggregate = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggr, "CNF_SERVICE",Document.class,"config",env);
```

I need to set the query to criteria and apply it to the match operation. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Match Operation you can achieve like below code:
Hope, it will helpful

Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
Query query= new Query(); query.addCriteria(criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("OwnerId").is(ownerId))); query.fields().include("SubServices"); query.fields().include("ServerGroupName"); query.fields().exclude("_id");
MongoTemplate.find(query, Map.Class, collectionName);